# Recursing Properly

Tags: php, recursion

I have several navigation related functions which I would like to have no depth limits.  These generate CSS menus, breadcrumb trails and the like.

I am stumped as to how I would make the functions follow each path to depth or to root without explicit looping.

The following is a typical example where I want the topmost parent of a page.  The topmost will have a value of zero in its `parent` field.

Here is the explicitly looped version:

```
function topPg() {
    $p = $this->retrieve("id = '$this->parent'");
    if ($p->parent != 0) {
        $gp = $this->retrieve("id = '$p->parent'");
        if ($gp->parent != 0) {
            $ggp = $this->retrieve("id = '$gp->parent'");
            if ($ggp->parent != 0) {
                $gggp = $this->retrieve("id = '$ggp->parent'");
                // ad naseum
            } else {
                return $ggp;
            }
        } else {
            return $gp;
        }
    } else {
        return $p;
    }
} // func
```

Anyone have advice or similar code or a tute link to help point the way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easily expressable as a while loop:

```
$node = $this;
while ($node->parent != 0) {
  $node = $this->retrieve("id = '$node->parent'");
}
```

`$node` now contains the topmost element.

Comment: I think you reversed $node and $this (that is, it should be $this->retrieve("id = '$node->parent'"), but the idea is clear.

Comment: @Stephan202: You're right. Thanks for the comment. I corrected the answer.

Comment: isn't $node = $this in the first place?

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had a hunch there was an elegant solution to this but while() had not occurred to me!

Answer (score 1):

[Welbog's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836494/recursing-properly/836543#836543) is the nicest, but for completeness I'll add another recursive solution:

```
function topPg() {
   function foo($p) {
     $gp = $this->retrieve("id = '$p->parent'");
     return ($gp->parent == 0) ? $p : foo($gp);
   }  

   return foo($this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it should work..:

```
function recurse( $pg )
{
    $parent_pg = $pg->retrieve( 'id = ' . $this->parent );

    if( $parent_pg->parent != 0 )
    {
        recurse( $parent_pg );
    }
    else
    {
        return $pg;
    }

}
```